# Can't get the &payment value, only get 0, although it is been assigned in C programming

Tags: c

[output](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10617716_10152671178792360_1142248594_n.jpg?oh=456c8a112f99d6da755dbc54b2d65e33&oe=53FE43F1&__gda__=1409145824_e9a9ceef9a622e670b832d32db1f3607)
I've been asked to design a cash register. the problem is the payment is always valued 0 although new value have been assigned using scan f. This is my 1st time posting here. sorry for the bad English. thanks

the problematic line

```
printf("\n\nGrand Total = RM ");
printf("%.2f\n",total);
printf("Payment = RM ");
scanf("%.2f\n",&payment);

printf("Payment = RM ");
printf("%.2f\n",payment);

balance = payment - total;
printf("Balance = RM ");
printf("%.2f\n",balance);
```

Full code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    /*initializing all possible data type*/
    int i,j=0,code,amount,lines=0;
    int id[100],stock[100],k=0;
    char name[100][20],product[100],key;
    float price[100],sum;
    float total =0,balance=0, payment =0;
    char ipname[100][20];
    int quantity[100], ch;
    float ipprice[100];
    float ipsub[100];

    FILE *fp;/*declaring file pointer (as "fp", can be any name), to call database file.*/

    fp=fopen("Item.txt","r"); /*open file, and error checking*/
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR in opening file. Text file not found in the directory\n");
        getch();
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while((ch=getc(fp))!=EOF)
        {
            if(ch=='\n')
            lines++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);/*close file after finishing operation*/

    fp=fopen("Item.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR in opening file. Text file not found in the directory\n");
        getch();
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=0;i<lines;i++)
        {
            fgets(product,sizeof(product),fp);
            id[i]=atoi(strtok(product,","));
            strcpy(name[i],strtok(NULL,","));
            price[i]=atof(strtok(NULL,","));
            stock[i]=atoi(strtok(NULL,"\n"));
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    /*printing @ displaying into cmd*/

    printf("=============================================================\n");
    printf(" Seremban Mart ----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("=============================================================\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<lines;i++)
    {
        printf("%2d:%-10s\t",i+1,name[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","No.","Product","Price","Quantity","Subtotal");
    printf("%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","===","=======","=====","========","========");

    do{
        k=0;
        if(j>0)
        {
            system("cls");
        }
        if(j>0)
        {
            printf("=============================================================\n");
            printf(" Seremban Mart ----------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("=============================================================\n\n");

            for(i=0;i<lines;i++)
            {
                printf("%2d:%-10s\t",i+1,name[i]);
            }
            printf("\n\n%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","No.","Product","Price","Quantity","Subtotal");
            printf("%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","===","=======","=====","========","========");

            for(k=0;k<j;k++)
            {
                printf("%-5d%-20s%-15.2f%-10d%.2f\n",k+1,
                    ipname[k],ipprice[k],quantity[k],ipsub[k]);
            }
        }

        /*calculation @ operation*/
        sum=0;
        amount=0;
        printf("\nProduct Code: ");
        scanf("%d",&code);
        i=code-1;
        printf("Quantity:");
        scanf("%d",&amount);
        system("cls");
        sum=price[i]*amount;
        total=total+sum;
        ipprice[j]=price[i];
        strcpy(ipname[j],name[i]);
        quantity[j]=amount;
        ipsub[j]=sum;

        printf("=============================================================\n");
        printf(" Seremban Mart ----------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("=============================================================\n\n");

        for(i=0;i<lines;i++)
        {
            printf("%2d:%-10s\t",i+1,name[i]);
        }

        printf("\n\n%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","No.","Product","Price","Quantity","Subtotal");
        printf("%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","===","=======","=====","========","========");

        for(k=0;k<=j;k++)
        {
            printf("%-5d%-20s%-15.2f%-10d%.2f\n",
                k+1,ipname[k],ipprice[k],quantity[k],ipsub[k]);
        }

        //printf("%d",j);
        printf("\nPress ESC on keyboard to finalize the bill or Press any key continue...\n");
        scanf("%c", &key);
        //if((key = getchar()) != '\027')
        //{
        //j++;
        //}
        while((key = getch()) != 27)
        {
            j++;
            break;
        }

    }
    while(key != 27);
    {
        printf("\n\nGrand Total = RM ");
        printf("%.2f\n",total);
        printf("Payment = RM ");
        scanf("%.2f\n",&payment);

        printf("Payment = RM ");
        printf("%.2f\n",payment);

        balance = payment - total;
        printf("Balance = RM ");
        printf("%.2f\n",balance);

        /*print receipt*/
        fp=fopen("Shopping Receipt.txt","w"); /*open file, and error checking*/
        if(fp==NULL)
        {
            printf("ERROR in opening file. Text file not found in the directory\n");
            getch();
            return 1;
        }

        const char *text = "Seremban Mart\nSeremban, Negeri Sembilan\nPhone: 06-6563887";
        fprintf(fp, text);

        char buff[100];
        time_t now = time (0);
        strftime (buff, 100, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000", localtime (&now));
        fprintf (fp,"\n\nDate & Time %s\n", buff);

        fprintf(fp,"\n\n%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","No.","Product","Price","Quantity","Subtotal");
        fprintf(fp,"%-5s%-20s%-15s%-10s%s\n","===","=======","=====","========","========");

        fprintf(fp,"\n\nGrand Total = RM ");
        fprintf(fp,"%.2f\n",total);
        fprintf(fp,"Payment = RM ");
        fprintf(fp,"%.2f\n",payment);
        fprintf(fp,"Balance = RM ");
        fprintf(fp,"%.2f\n",balance);
        fprintf(fp,"\n\nThank You and have a nice day");
        fprintf(fp,"\nRegards\nSeremban Mart");
        fclose(fp);
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please narrow down the code to the parts you have problem with. Preferably you should create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and have that in your question.

Comment: `scanf` has a return value so you can check if it worked.  You should always do that.  Not sure what the weirdness checking for the escape key is supposed to do, you should think about that logic a bit.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ...) then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out dis code instead!

```
    float payment = 0;
    printf("Payment = RM ");
    scanf("%f",&payment);
    printf("Payment = RM ");
    printf("%.2f\n",payment);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this line is a bit strange:

```
while(key != 27);
```

The semicolon means you have a tight loop and you stay there as long as The condition is true. You are lucky here that you key=27 at that point, otherwise your program would hang.

Second, the formatted input

```
scanf("%.2f\n",&payment);
```

is most probably not doing what you think it would do. Try

```
scanf("%f",&payment);
```

instead.

Comment: that's the end of the `do{  } while(key != 27);` loop

Comment: Ah ok, that I did not notice.